# How to merge multiple functions in JavaScript using Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I have many JavaScript modules that all of them export `data` and some other different functions. I want to merge all of these files into one file. Here are a few of them:

**File1.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            f1: 'something 1'
        }
    },
    foo() {
        // do something 1
    }
}
```

**File2.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            f2: 'something 2'
        }
    },
    bar() {
        // do something 2
    }
}
```

**File3.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            f3: 'something 3'
        }
    },
    zoo() {
        // do something 3
    }
}
```

The expected result is like this:

**Result.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            f1: 'something 1',
            f2: 'something 2',
            f3: 'something 3'
        }
    }, 
    foo() {
        // do something 1
    },
    bar() {
        // do something 2
    },
    zoo() {
        // do something 3
    }
}
```

I have seen a few articles that it could be more reliable if AST techniques are used. Here is a nice article: [Manipulating AST with JavaScript](https://lihautan.com/manipulating-ast-with-javascript/)

How can I do that with Babel?

Answer (score -1):

Using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (with Babel used a [loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/) to transform your code before bundling), you'd be able to move any functionality in the `data` method into its own module (keeping in mind this may mean handling different uses of that method in one module export).

In the other files, you could [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and reference the new utility function as needed.

Babel will transform the `import` statements into `require()` expressions, which will be used by Webpack to bundle these different modules for distribution. In that bundle, you'll see only one reference to the `data` module, even though you're importing it multiple times.